# convert a pyspark dataframe column in databricks as a list without using rdd

Tags: list, pyspark, databricks, rdd, flatmap

I trying to collect the values of a pyspark dataframe column in databricks as a list.

When I use the collect function

```
df.select('col_name').collect()
```

, I get a list with extra values.

based on some searches, using .rdd.flatmap() will do the trick

However, for some security reasons (it says rdd is not whitelisted), I cannot perform or use rdd. Could there be another way to collect a column value as a list?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a small dataframe, say you only have one column, I would suggest converting it to pandas dataframe and use `tolist()` function.

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
pdf_list = pdf['col_name'].tolist()
```

your output should be something like below:

```
['value1','value2','value3']
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get the same result if you don't want to use pandas:

```
col_list = [c[0] for c in df.select('col_name').collect()]
```